# reactive object in UI using Shiny R

Tags: r, user-interface, import, shiny, reactive

I have developed an app with Shiny R which can make some plots changing inputs (selecting the variables of a data frame).

Until now, I had the data frame loaded in the workspace, let's call it "mydata".

So in my UI area I had things like:

```
selectInput('varX3', "Variable 3", choices = names(mydata))
```

and worked perfectly.

But now I have decided to implement another module in the app where I can import data from a CSV, so I import the data, I check if the data is correct and then click a button called "confirm" that creates a reactive object, mydata().

What's the problem now? Well, there are two main problems:

1. mydata doesn't exist anymore, so when compiling it fail.
2. if I change mydata for mydata() in the UI, it will make an error too since mydata() doesn't exist until I import the data and confirm the data imported is OK and also there's no supposed to be reactive objects in the UI (as far as I know).

I have come up with the solution of using renderUI and uiOutput, but I found tedious to change everything.

Is there another way of solving the problem?

To explain me better:

first: I import data from a CSV and check if the data is OK, click a button creating a reactive object, a dataframe with the data: mydata()
second: I make plots of the variables of this data frame, so the data frame appears in the UI necessarily.

Comment: There's no other way than to use uiOutput and renderUI

Comment: Yeah I guess there's no other way. Thank you.

Comment: Actually there is one other way but i'm just writing is so you know it exists and it is not simplier :
you can initialize `selectInput('varX3', "Variable 3", choices = names(mydata))` in the UI. And in the server, add 
```observe({
updateSelectInput(session,'varX3', choices = names(myData()
})```